# Are parted's end positions inclusive or exclusive

Tags: parted

When creating partitions with `parted`, and when printing them back out, I was curious if the value for 'end' is inclusive or exclusive? Asked another way, is the second named in 'end' the last sector of the named partition or the first available sector for the next partition. Annoyingly, I could not find this information in the `info` pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are inclusive. You should end partitions on `(n mod 2048) - 1`.

```
Number  Start       End         Size        File system  Name   Flags
 2      2048s       624482303s  624480256s               ext2
 1      624482304s  625098751s  616448s                  fat32

(parted) rm 2                                                             
(parted) mkpart ext2 2048s 624482304s
Warning: You requested a partition from 2048s to 624482304s (sectors 2048..624482304).
The closest location we can manage is 2048s to 624482303s (sectors 2048..624482303).
Is this still acceptable to you?
Yes/No? yes
```